# C64 loading screen thoughts

Tags: c#, loading

I have made a loading screen (splash screen) just like the old C64.

I have used a series of picture boxes and just change the coloured image using a timer and a case statement.

```
switch (a)
{
    case 1: 
        pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
        pictureBox8.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
        pictureBox10.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
        pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
        pictureBox11.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
        pictureBox9.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
        break;
    case 2:
        pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.image2;
        pictureBox8.Image = Properties.Resources.image2;
        pictureBox10.Image = Properties.Resources.image2;
        break;
    case 3:
        pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.image3;
        pictureBox8.Image = Properties.Resources.image3;
        pictureBox10.Image = Properties.Resources.image3;
        break;
    case 4:
        pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.image4;
        pictureBox8.Image = Properties.Resources.image4;
        break;
    case 5:
        pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.image5;
        pictureBox8.Image = Properties.Resources.image5;
        break;
    case 6:
        pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.image6;
        pictureBox8.Image = Properties.Resources.image6;
        break;
    case 7:
        pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.image7;
        pictureBox8.Image = Properties.Resources.image7;
        break;
    case 8:
        pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.image8;
        pictureBox8.Image = Properties.Resources.image8;
        break;
}
```

its a bit nasty looking, how could I improve my code?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network. Look into http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I didnt know there was other sites sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look at the [Iterator design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/iterator-design-pattern).  You could create a class that represents a single stage, that class would have properties for each of the picture boxes and you would set the value of those properties to the relevant item in your resources file.

You then create instances of that object for each loading stage, put them in a collection and write an iterator to loop that collection.

Answer (score 0):

There are a two things I'd improve:

- Store your images in an array, so you don't have to repeat `case X/imageX` every time.
- Handle the common stuff first, then concentrate on the special cases.

You can declare the array in your form as a "fake" constant, since it won't change:

```
private readonly static Image[] myImages = new[] {
    Properties.Resources.image1,
    Properties.Resources.image2,
    Properties.Resources.image3,
    Properties.Resources.image4,
    Properties.Resources.image5,
    Properties.Resources.image6,
    Properties.Resources.image7,
    Properties.Resources.image8
}
```

and then use the following code in your Timer hander:

```
Image image = myImages[a-1];

pictureBox1.Image = image;
pictureBox8.Image = image;

// special cases
if (a == 1)
{
    pictureBox2.Image = image;
    pictureBox11.Image = image;
    pictureBox9.Image = image;
}
if (a >= 1 && a <= 3)
{
    pictureBox10.Image = image;
}
```